# extract javascript variable from a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

this is my first post. Hope I've observed all the rules properly.
I'm a JS beginner and I've been watching tutorials on thenewboston.com and w3schools and some others on Youtube but can't find the answer to my question.
I have a form that uses JS to dynamically add input rows and that works fine. However the last part I just can't get to work. It is the bit that is supposed to collate all the data entered by the user. 
This is what I have so far:

```
//get all the row data
function getData(TechRiskTable){

    try {
       var table = document.getElementById(TechRiskTable);
       var rowCount = table.rows.length;
       var jsonArray = new Array();
       for(var index=0; index < rowCount; index++) {
          var mapObj = {};
          var row = table.rows[index];
          var name1 = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
          var name2 = row.cells[1].childNodes[0];
          var name3 = row.cells[2].childNodes[0];
          var name4 = row.cells[3].childNodes[0];
          var name5 = row.cells[4].childNodes[0];

          mapObj['name1'] = name1.value;
          mapObj['name2'] = name2.value;
          mapObj['name3'] = name3.value;
          mapObj['name4'] = name4.value;
          mapObj['name5'] = name5.value;

         // document.write("Value in jsonArray " + name1.value + "<br />");
      }
    }catch(e) {
       alert(e);
    }
}
```

Ok, so I'm running this on a classic ASP page and the "onclick" does this:

```
response.write input type=submit onclick='getData(TechRiskTable);' value='Send to Reviewer'><input type=reset value='Start Again'>
```

My question is this: How can I extract the values the user entered into the added rows in the table "TechRiskTable" so I can insert them into a database. I don't need help with getting it into the dbase, I can do that myself. I'm just having trouble extracting the actual values. That "document.write" bit does actually display the correct values on the page when I have it uncommented, but that is still within the function. I can't find a way to access the entered data from OUTSIDE the function. I've tried using request.querystring but that doesn't return any data either.

I assume that I need to get them out of jsonArray() but I can't find anywhere I can get this to work.

Any clarification required please let me know. I didn't include all the code as this post would then be too long but if you need more just ask.

Cheers

Comment: If understand you correctly, you are trying to access the content of the mapObj JSON array from outside the function (let me know if I am wrong), if so, then changed the function to return the mapObj then access the values within mapObj outside the function as mapObj.name1, mapObj.name2....

Comment: I THINK you are correct (part of the problem I'm afraid), but yes, I'm trying to access the content of what the user entered in the form. How do I change the function to return the mapObj though? Sorry, as I said I'm a real beginner at this javascript.

Comment: Let me put it in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

```
  function getData(TechRiskTable){

    try {
       var table = document.getElementById(TechRiskTable);
       var rowCount = table.rows.length;
       var jsonArray = new Array();
       for(var index=0; index < rowCount; index++) {
          var mapObj = {};
          var row = table.rows[index];
          var name1 = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
          var name2 = row.cells[1].childNodes[0];
          var name3 = row.cells[2].childNodes[0];
          var name4 = row.cells[3].childNodes[0];
          var name5 = row.cells[4].childNodes[0];

          mapObj['name1'] = name1.value;
          mapObj['name2'] = name2.value;
          mapObj['name3'] = name3.value;
          mapObj['name4'] = name4.value;
          mapObj['name5'] = name5.value;

         // document.write("Value in jsonArray " + name1.value + "<br />");
         return mapObj;
      }
    }catch(e) {
       alert(e);
    }
    return null;
```

I am assuming you are calling this method from somewhere else,

```
var mapObj = getData(TechRiskTable);
if(mapObj!=null)
{
  alert("name1 is "+mapObj.name1+" and name2 is "+mapObj.name2);
}
```

Comment: hmmm.. No I don't think I'm understanding you correctly here. Once the user submits the form it redirects to the next page that validates and then inserts all the data into a database. When they click the submit button the "onclick" calls this method (onclick='getData(TechRiskTable);'). Is that what you mean? At the moment I have the next page simply displaying the data as follows:
TechRisk1 = request.querystring("mapObj.name1")
response.write "<p>TechRisk1 is " & TechRisk1
but that variable never shows up. If I can clarify more please let me know.

Comment: I've just tried again to put in that little bit you added at the end (I placed it outside the function) and I get a javascript alert saying: "Type Error: Cannot read property 'rows' of null. Does that help narrow down the issue?

Comment: @Terry, sorry for the delay, but when accessing the JSON object, it should not be between " ", this is how it be, var name1 = mapObj.name1.  How are you passing the data to the next page after submit, would you provide some info.

Comment: All other data from the form gets passed as vbscript variables which are called using the request.querystring command. However that doesn't work with the mapObj that I'm trying to get working here. So, there is a mix of data in the form - Mostly it's vbscript and this part of the form (TechRiskTable) is in javascript. Here is what I get the form to do when the user Submits:
response.write "<input type='hidden' value='NENC1Submit" & varNENNumber & "' name='x1'>"
response.write "<input type=submit onclick='getData(TechRiskTable);' value='Send to Reviewer'><input type=reset value='Start Again'>"

Comment: to add, it does not help to put this method in your onclick event if the method is returning data.  If this mapObj is being posted to the server so that another page is going to populate the data, then you should call your http POST or GET inside this method and not return the mapObj. Provide more details so that I can provide some more information

Comment: Just tried:
TechRisk1 = mapObj.name1
In vbscript if i don't use the "" it will generate an error (Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: 'mapObj')
So the vbscript is not recognising that the javascript has created the object called 'mapObj'. I'm missing a link somewhere...

Comment: ok, so I believe that the overall way I'm doing this is wrong. Can I email you the full code of both files? (the asp page and the js file)?

Comment: yes, please do, I was about to ask you for the vbscript

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't have your email address.

Comment: please send it to faljbour@yahoo.com